# Problem with Picker items scrolling in windows ToughPad

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, picker, xamarin.uwp

I am taking one picker like

```
    <Picker x:Name="picker" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding ItemName}"/>
```

My Item class is like

```
      public class Item
      {
         [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
         public int Id { get; set; }
         public string ItemName { get; set; } 
      }
```

Now I am adding picker itemssource like

```
      List<Item> items= new List<Item>();
      items= App.DAUtil.GetDevices();
      picker.ItemsSource = items;
```

here I am getting devices list from my local db. When ever I run the code in windows ToughPad the picker items are scrolling continuously but it is working fine when I run the code in Local Machine.Please help me for how to stop continuous scrolling of picker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Problem with Picker items scrolling in windows ToughPad

The matched native control is `ComboBox` in uwp platform, and loop scroll is by design in touch mode. If you want to tun it off you could refer this case [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37901456/7254781) then custom `Picker` renderer.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Picker), typeof(CustomPickerRenderer))]
namespace App35.UWP
{
    public class CustomPickerRenderer : PickerRenderer
    {

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if(Control != null)
            {
                Control.ItemsPanel = App.Current.Resources["CustomPanelTemplate"] as ItemsPanelTemplate;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Application.Resources**

```
<ResourceDictionary>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="CustomPanelTemplate">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Thanks @Nico Zhu - MSFT  now it is working perfectly.